# Custom directive value with bindonce in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got a ng-repeat with thousands of item in it, so I decided to tryout [bindonce](https://github.com/pasvaz/bindonce) to reduce the number of watches. But I couldn't figure out how to use it properly.
So now I got the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="card in cards">  
    <div class="item-box" draggable="{{card.category}}" itemId="{{card._id}}">
       <img ng-src="{{card.image}}" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

As I read in the [bindonce doc](https://github.com/pasvaz/bindonce), I should add the directive and use the bo-* directives, so I fugured out this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="card in cards" bindonce>  
    <div class="item-box" draggable="{{card.category}}" itemId="{{card._id}}">
       <img bo-src="card.image" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is how I can also use `{{card.category}}` and `{{card._id}}` using bind-once?

```
bo-attr bo-attr-draggable="card.category" bo-attr-itemId="card._id"
```

seems not to work, I'm not getting any errors, just nothing happens.

Result looks like

```
<div class="item-box ng-scope" bo-attr="" bo-attr-draggable="card.category" bo-attr-itemid="card._id" draggable="Pants" itemid="m--Pi">
```

Comment: That look right. You end up with two attributes, draggable and itemid, which have been evaluated draggable="Pants" itemid="m--Pi". What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Directives are not getting executed I think, I get no errors, but its not working.

Comment: Oh, draggable is a directive? In that case you should just be doing draggable="card.category" and in your directive you will $eval attrs.draggable and simply not set up a watch on it.

Comment: Can you give a simple example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bo-attr doesn't actually seem like what you want to be doing, you just want a directive to evaluate and bind data without creating any watches. I made a plnkr that I think is what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/sFPAjlRCkDuXU5UiM1U1?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
 });

// html
<div directive="name"></div>
// Dummy directive
app.directive('directive', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div bindonce bo-text="val"></div>',
    compile: function() {
      return {
        pre: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
          scope.val = scope.$eval(attrs.directive);
        }
      };
    }
  }
})
```

Woo no watches!

Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Just 1 more question, which solution do you think its better. If I make only 1 directive on the parent with $(document).("click", ".item-box", function()); or using this solution? because with this solution the directive will be executed hundred times or more.

Comment: If you are trying to learn angular I suggest not falling back to jQuery, as it will be confusing later where the clicks are coming from. If all you are doing is a click bind, you should be using ng-click. The dom class search is probably the same efficiency as attaching an ng-click to each repeated element.

Comment: Did you have more questions? If so, please ask, otherwise please mark as answered. Also, for the future, plnkr and jsfiddle are really great tools for sharing code here, as opposed to pictures of code.