# How to prevent angular from dirty checking certain portions of the DOM?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let us say I have a custom directive implemented like this:

```
<div my-custom-component></div>
```

This directive transforms the div into something with a whole lot of child elements. It's using a jQuery Widget internally. Is there a way to ask Angular to completely ignore this part of the visual-tree while dirty checking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom directive value with bindonce in Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592042/custom-directive-value-with-bindonce-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [Bind Once](http://swirlycheetah.com/native-bind-once-in-angularjs-1-3/) (v1.3+):

```
<my-custom-component name="::item"></my-custom-component>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to suggest that the specific binding (to "item") is one time. But, are you sure that this will prevent Angular from browsing this div's child-tree to look for more bindings that might be dirty? That's totally unrelated to "bind once" isn't it?